# VB.Net - NetworkStream stops sending after VBCrLf

Tags: vb.net, networkstream

I'm trying to send a byte array over TCP. It starts as a string (potentially 10s of thousands of lines long), gets converted to a byte array, and then is sent to the clients.

My issue is that the client is receiving the data in bursts as separate events but the subroutine that handles it needs to see all of it in one shot. To bandaid this I started programming in delimiters instead of the line breaks, but that presented a series of issues elsewhere, so instead of bandaiding the bandaid, I thought I'd come back to the root issue and seek your advice.

I suspect the issue is with the networkstream and that perhaps due to a lack of buffer it's deciding on it's own when to break up the data. I tried to implement the BufferStream, but I fumbled around into failure.

The string looks like this (pardon the weird formatting, I have lots of delimiting characters that are being misinterpreted by SO):

> GamePreloadedVariables`Classic`10000`Grain~Forestry~Coal~Silver~Gold~Market Mutual~~~~~~~~`128, 128, 0~0, 100, 0~64, 64, 64~192, 192, 192~255, 255, 0~255, 224, 192~~~~~~~~`100~100~100~100~100~100`120`5`True`False
>
> 0`Dividend`5`Market Mutual`5`100`100`100`100`100`100
>
> 1`Up`5`Forestry`1`100`105`100`100`100`101
>
> 2`Down`20`Grain`0`80`105`100`100`100`97
>
> ...etc

What ends up getting received initially is just the first line:

> > GamePreloadedVariables`Classic`10000`Grain~Forestry~Coal~Silver~Gold~Market Mutual~~~~~~~~`128, 128, 0~0, 100, 0~64, 64, 64~192, 192, 192~255, 255, 0~255, 224, 192~~~~~~~~`100~100~100~100~100~100`120`5`True`False

So my question is if it's possible to redesign how the data is sent so that the line breaks are included, along with the succeeding lines so that the entire string, however long, would be received in a single event?

**Here's the subroutine that I believe has the code that needs revamping:**

```
Public Sub SendGameFile(ByVal Preload As Byte())


    Dim networkStream As NetworkStream = Client.GetStream()


    If networkStream.CanWrite And networkStream.CanRead Then
        networkStream.Write(Preload, 0, Preload.Length)
    End If


End Sub
```

**Here's the clientside code (truncated to show only relevant code) that receives and interprets all incoming messages.**

```
Sub Read(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim Message As String = New StreamReader(Client.GetStream).ReadLine
    Client.GetStream.BeginRead(New Byte() {0}, 0, 0, AddressOf Read, Nothing)
    If Message.Length = 11 Then
        'irrelevant code
    ElseIf Message.Length > 100 Then
        Dim ContentChecker As String = Message.Substring(0, 22)
        If ContentChecker = "GamePreloadedVariables" Then
           Load_Preloaded_file(Message)
        End If
    Else
        'irrelevant code
    End If
End Sub
```

It's hopefully and probably obvious, just beyond my grasp at the moment. Thoughts?

Comment: You are totally mixing two networking concepts here. I am not at the desk right now but using a stream reader in an async read that also reads reads no bytes into an async buffer smells bad. Even if that BeginRead() only serves to re-enter the function on the next packet you are still creating a new Message for each call.

Comment: I had built the communications component of this game off an instant message platform and evolved it from there. All the game updates and server commands are sent via strings. What you are saying makes sense, however it's beyond me to implement a secondary delivery method that would run concurrently with the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce complexity, I would probably use blocking I/O and put the whole client sequence into a background worker or thread. There, just loop over ReadLine() until the stream is closed and return the deserialized game object.

Alternatively, copy from the network packets into a buffer or Queue and check for linebreaks. If found, remove the now complete lines from the buffer. Then wait for the next packet.

You may use this as a starting point, instead of waiting for packets asynchronusly it just reads until the stream ends and works with the completed string.

```
Module TcpListener

    Sub Main()
        Dim Client As New Net.Sockets.TcpClient(New Net.IPEndPoint(Net.IPAddress.Any, 0))
        Client.Connect("server.example.com", 80)
        Read(Client)
    End Sub

    Sub Read(Client As Net.Sockets.TcpClient)
        Dim MessageBuilder As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Using Writer As New IO.StreamWriter(Client.GetStream())
            Writer.WriteLine("GET / HTTP/1.1")
            Writer.WriteLine("Host: server.example.com")
            Writer.WriteLine("Connection: close")
            Writer.WriteLine("")
            Writer.Flush()
            Using Stream As New IO.StreamReader(Client.GetStream, False)
                Do
                    Dim Line As String = Stream.ReadLine()
                    ' Stop reading on End of Stream
                    If Line Is Nothing Then Exit Do
                    MessageBuilder.AppendLine(Line)
                Loop
            End Using
        End Using
        Dim Message As String = MessageBuilder.ToString()
        If Message.Length = 11 Then
            'irrelevant code
        ElseIf Message.Length > 100 Then
            Dim ContentChecker As String = Message.Substring(0, 22)
            If ContentChecker = "GamePreloadedVariables" Then
                Load_Preloaded_file(Message)
            End If
        Else
            'irrelevant code
        End If
    End Sub

    Sub Load_Preloaded_file(message As String)
        Console.Write(message)
    End Sub
End Module
```

For This example, I connected to a local Webserver and did a simple request for the index page. It would print out the HTTP Protocol and the content if it would start with "GamePreloadedVariables". Important is that the server Closes the Connection otherwise the loop would not end.

From here there is a long way to a good network code, i.e. the client should be the one to close the connection for performance reasons, async calls or a seperate thread could be used etc.

Comment: How would I use something like that in conjunction with what I'm already using? For example: `Dim Message As String = New StreamReader(Client.GetStream).ReadLine` is the declaration that reads all incoming messages (of which in this application are over a dozen unique types of content). I'd need some sort of way of identifying what the content of the stream is first before deciding how I would use it's content, would I not? Right now I decide that by delimiting the string. Or would your solution still work for all my existing needs with string commands?

Comment: I see why you are using ReadLine() - for a messagenger this makes sense - but ReadLine does exactly this, read a line up to a newline character and leave the remainder in the stream. But as it is right now you are sending multiple packets each containing mulitple lines and your client destroys the streamreader after reading the first line only.

Comment: Thanks for the example code in your edit. I'll see if I can put it to good use in and check back with my success!

Comment: I just gave it a quick test run, best I could with my limited knowledge, and the program hangs on `Dim Line As String = Stream.ReadLine()` in the Do loop. I'll poke at it tomorrow to see if I can figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: See my Warning "Important is..." - Readline blocks / waits until a complete Line (including CR/LF) is encountered, make sure you send a NewLine after each Text line and then close the stream.